# Is it possible to specify a function directly in a struct declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, function-pointers

For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
    int (*baz)(int);
};

int testFunc(int x)
{
    return x;
}

Foo list[] = {
    { 0, &testFunc },
    { 1, 0 } // no func for this.
};
```

In this example, I'd rather put the function directly into the list[] initializer rather than using a pointer to a function declared elsewhere; it keeps the related code/data in the same place.

Is there a way of doing this? I tried every syntax I could think of and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This looks awfully close to a manual implementation of dynamic dispatch... have you considered using inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean something like:

```
Foo list[] = {
    { 0, int (*)(int x) { return x;} },
    { 1, 0 } // no func for this.
};
```

then, no, it's not possible. You're talking about [anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), something C++ doesn't yet support (as of August 2011).

C++0x is adding support for [lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions), which is pretty much the same thing and your syntax would probably be something like:

```
Foo list[] = {
    { 0, [](int x) { return x; } },
    { 1, 0                       }
};
```

However, if your intention is simply to keep the code and data in close proximity, then just keep them in close proximity (the same C source file, with the code immediately preceding the data).

Comment: Unfortunately, that list is potentially quite large, and with potentially multiple functions, the closest proximity I can realistically achieve isn't going to be that close. I guess I'll just have to live with it for now, or refactor.

Comment: Note that lambdas (anonymous functions) have a complete different (and unknown) type, so you would have to change the definition of the struct. In this case to something in the lines of `struct Foo { int bar; std::function<int (int)> baz; };` which in turns means that the type is no longer a POD (not even standard layout)

Comment: @Flynn, I would consider putting them in their own source file and having _only_ the list and related functions in that file (nothing else). You could even call your functions `fn0`, `fn1` and so on, based on your first parameter in each array element (to be able to find them easily with editor search).

Answer (score 0):

In C++0x you may use lambdas to keep your data and code together, but that would make code hard to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) which don't exist in C or C++ (although Clang supports it unofficially, and it will be added in C++0x.)

Comment: There is support for anonymous functions in other compilers: Intel was the first (AFAIK), then VS2010, g++...